# How can I view the changes made after a revision is committed and parse it for comments?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I was hoping to automate some tasks related to SubVersion, so I got SharpSvn. Unfortunately I cant find much documentation for it.

I want to be able to view the changes after a user commits a new revision so I can parse the code for special comments that can then be uploaded into my ticket system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to browse SharpSvn you can use [http://docs.sharpsvn.net/](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/). The documentation there is far from complete as the focus is primarily on providing features. Any help on enhancing the documentation (or SharpSvn itself) is welcome ;-)

To use log messages for your issue tracker you can use two routes:

1. A post-commit hook that processes changes one at a time
2. A scheduled service that calls 'svn log -r <last-retrieved>:HEAD' every once in a while.

The last daily builds of SharpSvn have some support for commit hooks, but that part is not really api-stable yet.

You could create a post commit hook (post-commit.exe) with:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  SvnHookArguments ha;
  if (!SvnHookArguments.ParseHookArguments(args, SvnHookType.PostCommit, false, out ha))
  {
    Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid arguments");
    Environment.Exit(1);
  }

  using (SvnLookClient cl = new SvnLookClient())
  {
    SvnChangeInfoEventArgs ci;
    cl.GetChangeInfo(ha.LookOrigin, out ci);

    // ci contains information on the commit e.g.
    Console.WriteLine(ci.LogMessage); // Has log message

    foreach(SvnChangeItem i in ci.ChangedPaths)
    {
       //
    }
  }
}
```

(For a complete solution you would also have to hook the post-revprop-change, as your users might change the log message after the first commit)

Answer (score 2):

Is this of any use?

http://blogs.open.collab.net/svn/2008/04/sharpsvn-brings.html

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether subversion hooks (at the svn server) might not be another approach here? I have not tried it, but [CaptainHook](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/07/27/IntroducingCaptainHookASubversionHookFrameworkFor.NET.aspx) appears to offer svn->.NET hook integration.

Comment: CaptainHook is a good solution for using hooks in .NET. Be sure to grab the patches. One fixes 2x bugs